# External js is not working when using node.js readFileSync() to read the HTML file as a string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on vs code extension development(web view) and I want to separate the HTML file and the JS file.

When I use readFileSync() to read the HTML file, it successfully parses the HTML element in the web view, but the Javascript is not working.

I have tried to directly put all the JS code into the  tag and it works. Therefore, I think maybe it is the relative path problem. I have tried different types of path:

'../js/main.js', '..\js\main.js'

and also the absolute path from my C drive and they are not working. I really have no idea about it.

My file structure:

[image]

My file reader from my extension.ts:

```
function getWebviewContent(url: vscode.Uri) {
    // url.fsPath : xxxx\helloworld\src\html\index.html
    return fs.readFileSync(url.fsPath, "utf8");
}
```

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello World Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hello Form </h1>
    <div className="form-row">
        <div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" className="form-control" id="inputEmail" ref="email" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputName" ref="name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="greeting" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 10px">Submit</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS File:

```
(function() {
    const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
    const btn = document.getElementById('greeting');


    btn.onclick = () => {
        const name = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
        console.log(name)
        vscode.postMessage({
            command: 'greeting',
            text: "Hello, " + name
        });
    }
}())
```

I have a new trial and it works, but now I don't know how to reference the correct path in my HTML file.

I changed my file reader function:

```
function getWebviewContent(url: vscode.Uri) {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello World Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Hello Form </h1>
        <div className="form-row">
            <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="inputEmail" ref="email" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputName" ref="name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="greeting" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 10px">Submit</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="${url}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>`;
}
```

That is how I call the function:

```
const scriptPathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(context.extensionPath, 'src/js', 'main.js'));
const scriptUri = scriptPathOnDisk.with({ scheme: 'vscode-resource' });
panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent(scriptUri);
```

When I print out getWebviewContent(), it is a html string and I found that:

```
<script src="vscode-resource:/c%3A/Users/Kelvinyu/Documents/test/helloworld-vscode-extension/helloworld/src/js/main.js">
```

I think this is the correct path, but how can I reference this in my html, I want it to be relative.

Comment: are you sure about paths? maybe `src="../js/main.js"` from your nodeJS path is not pointing to correct path

Comment: I have a new trial and found the correct path. But I got a new problem and I have updated the question. Can you have a look?